# detect click on shape pygame

Tags: geometry, pygame, mouse, collision

so I have tried detecting the collision by making 2 shapes but there is some kind of mistake in it and I am wondering if there are easier ways. so this is what i tried:

```
cursorSurface = pygame.Surface((0,0))
cursor = pygame.draw.rect(cursorSurface, (0,0,0),(mouseX,mouseY,2,2))            
mouse_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(cursorSurface,255)
mouse_rect = cursor    
if mouseAction[0] == 'move':
    if mouseX > x and mouseX < xEnd and mouseY > y and mouseY < yEnd:          
        topTriangle = selectedSquare.subsurface(x+4,y+4,xEnd-(x+5),int((yEnd-(y+5))*0.25))
        bottomTriangle = selectedSquare.subsurface(x+4,y+4+int((yEnd-(y+5))*0.75),xEnd-(x+5),int((yEnd-(y+5))*0.25))
        leftTriangle = selectedSquare.subsurface(x+4,y+4,int((xEnd-(x+5))*0.25),yEnd-(y+5))
        rightTriangle = selectedSquare.subsurface(x+4+int((xEnd-(x+5))*0.75),y+4,int((xEnd-(x+5))*0.25),yEnd-(y+5))

        collisionTop_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(topTriangle,255)
        collisionTop_rect = topTriangle.get_rect()                    
        collisionTop_rect.topleft = (0,0)

        pygame.draw.rect(selectedSquare, colorDark,(x+5+int((xEnd-(x+5))*0.25),y+5+int((yEnd-(y+5))*0.25),int((xEnd-(x+5))*0.75)-int((xEnd-(x+5))*0.25)-2,int((yEnd-(y+5))*0.75)-int((yEnd-(y+5))*0.25)-2))     
        pygame.draw.polygon(topTriangle, colorDark, ((1,0), (topTriangle.get_width()-2,0), (int((xEnd-(x+7))/2),(int((yEnd-(y+7))/2)-1))))
        pygame.draw.polygon(leftTriangle, colorDark, ((0,1), (0,leftTriangle.get_height()-2), (int((xEnd-(x+7))/2)-1,(int((yEnd-(y+7))/2)))))
        pygame.draw.polygon(bottomTriangle, colorDark, ((1,yEnd-(y+6)-int((yEnd-(y+5))*0.75)), (bottomTriangle.get_width()-2,yEnd-(y+6)-int((yEnd-(y+5))*0.75)), (int((xEnd-(x+7))/2),(int((yEnd-(y+7))/2)+1-(yEnd-(y+5))*0.75))))
        pygame.draw.polygon(rightTriangle, colorDark, ((xEnd-(x+6)-int((xEnd-(x+5))*0.75),1), (xEnd-(x+6)-int((xEnd-(x+5))*0.75),rightTriangle.get_height()-2), (int((xEnd-(x+7))/2)+1-int((xEnd-(x+5))*0.75),(int((yEnd-(y+7))/2)))))

        screen.blit(selectedSquare, (0,0))
        if collisionTop_mask.overlap(mouse_mask,(mouse_rect.left-collisionTop_rect.left,mouse_rect.top-collisionTop_rect.top)) != None:
            print('detect')
```

but i have also seen this methode:

```
if topTriangle.get_rect().collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
```

the problem is that this only detects squares and I need to detect a triangle. could someone pleas help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this I think (didn't test):

```
posx, posy = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
posx -= XCoordinateOfTopTriangleOnScreen
posy -= YCoordinateOfTopTriangleOnScreen
if topTriangle.get_at((posx,posy)) == colorDark:
    print('detect')
```

Comment: well this doesn't work with subsurface because it just takes al the colors of the origional surface but i can just change it a little so thanks!

Comment: @thegunmaster Accept the answer as the best one then.