# How do I check to see if a mouse click is within a circle in pygame?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

white = 255,255,255
cyan = 0,255,255

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption('Circle Click Test')

stop = False

while not stop:
    gameDisplay.fill(white)

    pygame.draw.circle(gameDisplay,cyan,(400,300),(100))

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            ####################################################  

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    pygame.display.update()
```

Here I have a circle on the screen, and I would like to check to see if the user
clicked within the circle. I know how to do this with a rectangle, I would assume it would be similar. Thanks for any help, I am quite new to pygame.

here is what I have for rectangles:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

white = 255,255,255
cyan = 0,255,255

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption('Circle Click Test')

rectangle = pygame.Rect(400,300,200,200)

stop = False

while not stop:
    gameDisplay.fill(white)

    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, cyan,rectangle,4)

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            click = rectangle.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())

            if click == 1:
                print 'CLICKED!'

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Can you paste your rectangle code?

Comment: Show us your rectangle hit code and what you have tried for circles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the distance formula:

```
################################################################################
# Imports ######################################################################
################################################################################

from pygame.locals import *
import pygame, sys, math

################################################################################
# Screen Setup #################################################################
################################################################################

pygame.init()
scr = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
pygame.display.set_caption('Box Test')

################################################################################
# Game Loop ####################################################################
################################################################################

while True:
    pygame.display.update(); scr.fill((200, 200, 255))
    pygame.draw.circle(scr, (0, 0, 0), (400, 300), 100)

    x = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]
    y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1]

    sqx = (x - 400)**2
    sqy = (y - 300)**2

    if math.sqrt(sqx + sqy) < 100:
        print 'inside'

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

################################################################################
################################################################################
################################################################################
```

Comment: @RomanFormicola I actually made an error with the mouse index. See now.

Answer (score 1):

you could sample the pixel like this
[detect click on shape pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712128/detect-click-on-shape-pygame)
otherwise use pythagoras to get the distance from the centre.

As Malik shows, pythagoras works well for circles, but for general solid colour shapes you can do:

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
  click = gameDisplay.get_at(pygame.mouse.get_pos()) == cyan

  if click == 1:
      print 'CLICKED!'
```